# Disable autocomplete option on Google Chrome using MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We tried to use Autocomplete attribute of textbox and dynamic value on name attribute of textbox but unable to disbale autocomplete option on Google Chrome but it work perfectly fine on IE, Firefox.

Comment: You can try `<form autocomplete="off"> 
  <input type="text" id="input_name" autocomplete="none"/> `

Comment: Please add some code, and add `autocomplete="off"` in each `input`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

If the input is inside the form, you should do like this:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

And the input you should do

```
<input type="text" id="input_name" autocomplete="none"/>
```

Comment: Applying direct "none" value on autocomplete attribute does not work. I used settimeout for none value -  setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("disableAutofill");

            $('input[autocomplete="off"]').attr("autocomplete", "none");//.disableAutofill();
            //$('input[autocomplete="off"]').disableAutofill();
            //$('input[autocomplete="off"]').disableAutofill();
           
        }, 100);

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample block using Razor

```
<div class="position-relative form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "off" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "font-style:italic;" })
</div>
```

Hope this one helps